# How can I clean up all X2go user session?

Tags: ubuntu

I have an ubuntu system.

Some users can access with X2go client, but some users can't.

OS(Win/Mac) doesn't matter, who can access from Windows can access from Mac too.

So I commanded as below.

```
sudo service x2goserver restart
```

But there are no changes. Does anyone have good solution?

Comment: What x manager are they using ? Are the different ?
I can only login using XFCE and LXDE.
Also if it ever offers to continue a session, terminate it and start a new session

Comment: Maybe your are looking for this: http://lab.demog.berkeley.edu/LabWiki/index.php/Help:X2go_bankruptcy